# Return error from a private method in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Below is the update action in the controller. The issue I am facing here is that I am not able add the error to the @agency.errors if there are errors in the agency_information private method. I want to prevent the @agency.save action is there are errors in the @agency.errors and render json: { errors: @agency.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity. Please help me solve this issue.

```
class AgenciesController < MyAccountController
 def update      
    @agency_params = agency_params
    @agency = current_agency
    agency_information
    render json: { errors: @agency.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity unless @agency.save
 end

 private
 def agency_information
  @agency = current_agency
  gateway = ChargeIO::Gateway.new(secret_key: Settings.lawpay.secret_key)
  card = gateway.create_card(token_id: params[:id])
  if card.messages.empty?
    @agency_params[:card][:number] = gateway_card.number
  else
    @agency.errors.full_messages << card.messages.collect(&:message).join("\n")
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want add errors to a model, you should use `.errors.add(:base, message)`. In there `:base` can be any of your models attributes if the error is about a specific attribute or `:base` if it's about the model in general.

Check [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add) for more details.

`full_messages` is just a getter. Adding errors to there does nothing.

Do take note that if you call `@agency.save`, validations will be rerun and existing errors will be cleared. You need to either add that validation to the model level or check for errors manually before calling `.save`.

Comment: Long line, didn't notice. My bad. The point still stands though, save will clear the errors so you'll have to check errors manually before calling save or adding the validation to the model.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the errors to a model object using following code will not work

```rb
@agency.errors.full_messages << card.messages.collect(&:message).join("\n")
```

Instead do following

```rb
error_message = card.messages.collect(&:message).join("\n")
@agency.errors.add(:card, error_message)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your @agency and whenever you get error you want to return that, in that case you can do something like this,

```
def update
@agency.save!
render json: {"result": {"data": {@agency}}
rescue StandardError => e
  render json: {"error": 
 {"status":500,"message":@agency.errors.full_messages.merge}}, status: 500
end
```